# Nightwatch: How load tests embedded in codebase?

Tags: nightwatch.js

Is there a way to configure Nightwatch to only target files with a certain naming pattern, e.g. "app/**/*.test.js" ?

At the moment, all my nightwatch test files are in a single folder, I would like to place my test files adjacent to the components they are testing, as I do with my unit test and stylesheets, is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://nightwatchjs.org/guide#command-line-options
Looks like `--filter` is what you want.

Comment: Ye the filter configuration option is actually what I was looking for, thanks a lot!